# Re-Indexing Home Page - HTML/DOM Change

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing

(Site on WordPress)

Currently, our company homepage is using images instead of divs to display our main products/solutions. As the SEO, I wanted to remove these images (which consist of mostly text) in order to replace them with more SEO-rich header and paragraph tags.

Ultimately, this means changing the DOM, and I wanted to ask if this will hurt the site (in terms of rankings) when the page is re-indexed.

The UI will be the same, but I figured that the new crawl-able content will supplement the current content on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in fact you may expect improvements SEO-wise. This is because text on images aren't indexed<sup>1</sup> and normal text is.

There are various tools available on the internet which allow you to view your page as a general crawler. If you view your page in text-only mode, not much remains of a website based on images.

And to adress another issue you might have understood wrong: Changes to the DOM aren't necessarily bad<sup>2</sup>. In fact, updating, improving and maintaining your website might actually improve your ranking because you appear to keep your content up to date, which is the kind of content crawlers prefer to serve their users. The trick is to define "how to improving your site".

*<sup>1</sup> Maybe they can now, but you should asume they can't.*
*<sup>2</sup> Changing the DOM too much **is** bad when you use Javascript for too much changes*

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't think about the general benefit of updating the content boosting the site ranking.